# I need help to fetch the data from database

Tags: java, iteration, resultset

This is my table

```
FirstName----LastName----City--------State 
Ram----------Padhan------Houston-----TX 
Ram----------Padhan------Washingtom--MI 
Ram----------Padhan------Alok--------BG 
Keiry--------Lading------Azan--------BL 
Keiry--------Lading------Aror--------BS
```

How can I fetch the data so that my output will be:

```
FirstName: Ram--LastName: Padhan 
City: Houston--State:TX 
City:Washington--State:MI 
City:Alok--State:BG
FirstName: Keiry--LastName: Lading 
City: Azan--State:BL 
City:Aror--State:BS
```

Beside getting the value by each row:

```
FirstName: Ram--LastName: Padhan 
City: Houston--State:TX 
FirstName: Ram--LastName: Padhan 
City:Washington--State:MI
```

Here's what I did. The output I am getting is just first row firstname and lastname whereas for state and city columns , I am getting value till the end row.

```
public class Practise 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Connection conn = null; 
        Statement stmt = null; 

        try { 
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ; 
             String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table_name"; 

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root" ); 

             stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement(); 

             String sql = "SELECT First_Name ,Last_Name ,City_Name , State_Name, FROM table_name"; 

             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

             while(rs.next())
             {
                String first = rs.getString("First_Name"); 
                String last = rs.getString("Last_Name"); 
                System.out.print("First: " + first); 
                System.out.println("Last: " + last);

                do 
                { 
                    String city = rs.getString("City_Name"); 
                    String state = rs.getString("State_Name"); 
                    System.out.println("City: " + city);
                    System.out.println("State: " + state); 
                    System.out.println(); 
                } while(rs.next());
             }
             rs.close(); 
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        { 
             se.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally { 
             try { 
                if (stmt != null) 
                    conn.close(); 
             }
             catch(SQLException se)
             { } 
             try {
                 if (conn != null) 
                     conn.close(); 
             }
             catch(SQLException se)
             { 
                 se.printStackTrace(); 
             } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is unreadable. Actually format your whole question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `while` loop nested inside another `while` loop.

Change it to this:

```
while(rs.next())

{ 
String first = rs.getString("First_Name"); 

String last = rs.getString("Last_Name"); 

System.out.print("First: " + first); 

System.out.println("Last: " + last);
String city = rs.getString("City_Name"); 

String state = rs.getString("State_Name"); 

System.out.println("City: " + city);

 System.out.println("State: " + state); 

System.out.println(); 
}
```

**Edit** I misunderstood your question initially.  This is pseudo code as I haven't tried this, but you'll need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT First_Name ,Last_Name , group_concat("City:",City_Name , "--State:", State_Name separator "\n") as data FROM table_name group by First_Name, Last_Name
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. See the output following `"How can I fetch the data so that my output will be"` in the question.

Comment: @Dukeling Oh, you're right...amazing what a difference formatting makes...

Comment: Getting rid of second loop will get me the value by each rows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 2 tables. One for the person, the other for the city/state. Select the persons first, then as you iterate, use a key to look up the city/state.

Comment: I can't use two tables. Its part of my work. I have to fetch the data using single table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person previousPerson = null;
Person nextPerson = null;
while(rs.next()) {
    nextPerson = new Person(rs.getString("First_Name"), rs.getString("Last_Name")); 
    if( ! nextPerson.equals(previousPerson)) {
        previousPerson = nextPerson;
        System.out.println(previousPerson); 
    }
    City city = new City(rs.getString("City_Name"), rs.getString("State_Name")); 
    System.out.println(city);
}
```